# Powershell delete files older than 30 days and log

Tags: powershell

I'm using this code to delete files older than 30 days

```
Function Remove_FilesCreatedBeforeDate {
  $Path = "\\servername\path"
  $Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
  $ValidPath = Test-Path $Path -IsValid

  If ($ValidPath -eq $True) {
    "Path is OK and Cleanup is now running"
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse  | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $Date } | Remove-Item -Recurse -force -Verbose
  }
  Else { 
    "Path is not a ValidPath"
  }
}

Remove_FilesCreatedBeforeDate
```

Now I want to log which files were deleted, and also whether there was an error or the path isn't valid. Can anyone help me here?

**//EDIT**

Im Now using this Code (Thanks to Efie for helping)

```
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter()]$LogPath = 'C:\Admin\scripts\Clean_Folder\Log\log.txt',
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$Message
    )
    process {
        $timeStampedMessage = "[$(Get-Date -Format 's')] $Message"
        $timeStampedMessage | Out-File -FilePath $LogPath -Append
    }
}

Function Remove-FilesCreatedBeforeDate {
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter()]$Path = '\\servername\path\',
        [Parameter()]$Date = $(Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
    )
    process {
        if(-not (Test-Path $Path -IsValid)) {
            "Path $Path was invalid" | Write-MyLog
            return
        }
    
        "Path $Path is OK and Cleanup is now running" | Write-MyLog
    
        try {
            Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | 
            Where-Object { 
                $_.LastWriteTime -lt $Date 
            } | Remove-Item -recurse -force -verbose | Write-MyLog
        }
        catch {
            "Remove-Item failed with message $($_.Exception.Message)" | Write-MyLog
        }
       
    }
    
}
Write-MyLog
Remove-FilesCreatedBeforeDate
```

Two files getting deleted but i just see this in my Log

```
[2021-07-22T16:27:53] Path \\servername\path\ is OK and Cleanup is now running
```

I dont see which files getting deleted sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple implementation for your example would be something like this:

```
Function Remove-FilesCreatedBeforeDate {
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]$Path = '\some\default\path',
        [Parameter()]$Date = $(Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
    )
    process {
        if(-not (Test-Path $Path -IsValid)) {
            "Path $Path was invalid" | Write-MyLog
            return
        }
    
        "Path $Path is OK and Cleanup is now running" | Write-MyLog
    
        try {
            Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | 
            Where-Object { 
                $_.LastWriteTime -lt $Date 
            } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Verbose
        }
        catch {
            "Remove-Item failed with message $($_.Exception.Message)" | Write-MyLog
        }
    }
}
  
function Write-MyLog {
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter()]$LogPath = 'default\log\path\log.txt',
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$Message
    )
    process {
        $timeStampedMessage = "[$(Get-Date -Format 's')] $Message"
        $timeStampedMessage | Out-File -FilePath $LogPath -Append
    }
}
```

### Some notes:

#### Advanced Functions

`process { }`, `[Cmdletbinding()]`, and `[Parameter()]` are what turn your function into an 'advanced' function. You get to use loads of built in features normally reserved for compiled cmdlets this way.

For example, you could now suppress errors with `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` like you're used to doing with native Powershell cmdlets.

You can pipe your messages to your logging function by adding `ValueFromPipelin` to your parameter.

Those really just brush the surface of the extra capabilities you get.

Here is some information. I would recommend getting in the habit of writing them like this if you plan to use them in the future.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.1

#### Error Handling

I'd recommend looking into this documentation by Microsoft on error handling:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions?view=powershell-7.1

#### Naming Conventions

I would also recommend taking a look at this about PowerShell function naming conventions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?view=powershell-7

By PowerShell standards it would make more sense to name your function `Remove-FilesCreatedBeforeDate` with the dash separating verb-action instead of the underscore.

#### Logging

If you want a little more control and a few more features for logging your functions, here is some information on a tried and true solution for PowerShell using PSFramework:

https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-logging/

Good luck! Hope some of that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sadly no logfile is created when i run your Script :(

Comment: Yes i did all it logs is the date. I also had to add "Remove_FilesCreatedBeforeDate" after the last function after that a log file was created but just the time is logged.

Comment: Yes you need to call the function in order for it to execute. You may also want to reload your powershell session if you have an old version of the function loaded in memory. I'd recommend debugging in something like ISE or VScode to see where you're going wrong. I just tested the logging function on PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell Core. You're going to have to do a little bit of the work yourself on this one! It will be a good learning experience to walk through the code.

Comment: My problem is that i have no clue about Powershell just the basic basic. I found that delete script and changed it as far as i could. Your tips are nice but i dont understand them. So i guess i have to find another solution as i cant change your code to be working. I even started a new Powershell ISE

Comment: Edited my first post maybe you can help at the last step :)

Answer (score 0):

Could `Start-transcript` with `Try and catch` be your solution here?

`Start-Transcript` logs everything that you do and the errors.

I tried this and this does what you want

```
Start-Transcript -Path "$PSScriptRoot\RemoveAccountLog.txt" -Force -Append
Get-Date -Format "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM"
 Try
  { # Start Try 
  $Path = "\\servername\path"
  $Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)


    $TestPath = Test-Path -Path $Path -PathType Container
    If ( $TestPath -Eq $Null )
     { # Start If
      Write-Host "The $TestPath String is empty, Path is not a valid"
     } # End If

     Else
      { # Start Else
      Write-host "Path is OK and Cleanup is now running... 0%"
      $GetFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force |
       Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $Date } |
       Remove-Item -Recurse -force -Verbose  | 
       Write-host "Path is OK and Cleanup is now running... 100%" -ForegroundColor Green
      } # End Else
  } # End Try

Catch
  {  # Start Catch
   Write-Warning -Message "## ERROR## " 
   Write-Warning -Message "## Script could not start ## " 
   Write-Warning $Error[0]
  }  # End Catch
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Unix its Simple
find /var/log/hive -type f -mtime +30 -delete